# Struggling to install Azure DevOps deployment agent on Linux machine

Tags: ubuntu, azure-devops, ubuntu-20.04

So I'm trying to install an Azure DevOps deployment agent on Linux machines (Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa). I tried to do so by executing the the code snippet, that the Azure DevOps site generates. However I keep getting this annoying error message pointing to a missing libssl library:

`No usable version of the libssl was found`

There is a YouTube video ([How to solve the "No usable version f the libssl was found" in GitHub Actions and Azure Pipelines](https://youtube.com/watch?v=EbEzgxLi8YY)) explaining how to get around this issue. Basically the idea is to either upgrade to the latest .NET Core version (I assume the agent uses .NET Core) or to downgrade the incompatible libssl library.

However none of that worked for me. First of all, the .NET Core Framework doesn't seem to be installed after the installation of the agent has errored out, maybe there was just some checking beforehand, fine whatever. But after I installed the latest .NET Core runtime, the same error pops up.

Secondly, I'm unable to locate the suggested older version of the libssl-dev package (looking for version 1.0.x). On pkgs.org there are no entries for version 1.0.x for Ubuntu, same on packages.ubuntu.com. And when I type in `apt list -a libssl-dev` I also only get version 1.1.x.

Why is this so difficult? Has anyone tried using the 1.0.x version of libssl-dev and did it work? And how did you get a hold of it?

Any suggestion greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I'm running into the same problem.

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops#check-prerequisites),

> The agent is based on .NET Core 3.1

And looking at the file structure, the agent seems to be a [self contained .net application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli#self-contained-deployment). So I'm quite sure that installing another version of .net is just useless in that case.

[edit] Finally in my case it was not working because I was using the latest 22.04 LTS. According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#supported-distributions), only .net 6 is supported on this one. As the self contained build agent is running a .net 3.1 behind the scenes, I conformed to the latest Ubuntu LTS version with .net core 3.1 support which is 20.04.

Are you sure of your version of ubuntu @DanDan?

Answer (score 2):

Just try this. The problem is linked with OpenSSL 3.0, but you can add OpenSSL 1.1

```
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1o.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.1.1o
./config
```

Answer (score 2):

I also encounter the same problem on ubuntu 22.10. I have tried several methods online and finally managed to install libssl and openssl, as a result the agent can be run successfully.

```
wget -c http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb
apt install ./libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb
wget -c http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb
apt install ./openssl_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

Dears;

I solved the issue by using a newer version of Azure DevOps Agent.

Comment: where did you get hold of the newer version?

Comment: wget https://vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net/agent/3.220.0/vsts-agent-linux-x64-3.220.0.tar.gz

Answer (score 1):

Don't downgrade the openssl version on your Ubuntu machine!

> Go to : https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/releases

Get the latest release & replace it with the release version that you had, and install your new agent.

Enjoy!!

Comment: wget https://vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net/agent/3.220.0/vsts-agent-linux-x64-3.220.0.tar.gz resolved

Answer (score 0):

For those who might still be having this issue. Installing a newer version of the Azure DevOps Agent will solve it. Here is a link.

https://vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net/agent/3.220.0/vsts-agent-linux-x64-3.220.0.tar.gz

the go ahead to run:

```
tar zxvf vsts-agent-linux-x64-3.220.0.tar.gz
rm vsts-agent-linux-x64-3.220.0.tar.gz

./config.sh
```

Usage:
./svc.sh [install, start, stop, status, uninstall]

Commands:

> install [user]: Install agent service as Root or specified user.
> start: Manually start the agent service.    stop: Manually stop the
> agent service.    status: Display status of agent service.
> uninstall: Uninstall agent service.